# Is it possible to query TFS system for any work items that contain an attachment ends with .sql?

Tags: file, tfs, workitem, tfs-workitem

For every release we would like to round up all the work items that contain a .sql attachments  to run on our staging server.  Is there a way to query TFS?  Or is this something that has to be done directly to the TFS server database?

Any suggestions?

We're using Team Foundation Server 2010 RTM.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at X:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools. There exists a plenty of useful command tools.

Comment: Indeed, not a very useful answer.